# Cannot figure out the problem with key and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prop

I need help with figuring out why when I use a function component, I do not get a warning of this type:

> index.js:1446 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

When I use a class component, this warning pops out.

Thank you in advance for clarification.

function component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import VideoItem from './VideoItem';

const VideoList = ({videos, selectedVideo}) =>{
    const renderedItems = videos.map((video) =>{
        return <VideoItem key={video.id.videoId} video={video} selectedVideo={selectedVideo}/>
    })
    return <div>{renderedItems}</div>
}

export default VideoList;
```

class Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import VideoItem from './VideoItem';

class VideoList extends Component {
    render() { 
        const renderedItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
            return <div><VideoItem key={video.id.videoId} video={video} selectedVideo={this.props.selectedVideo}/></div>
        })
        return(
            <div>{renderedItems}</div>
        )
    }
}
 
export default VideoList;
```

Comment: How are you consuming `VideoList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 const renderedItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
            return <VideoItem key={video.id.videoId} video={video} selectedVideo={this.props.selectedVideo}/>
        })
```

key must be on Div or remove it

Comment: I added the key in the div and still getting the same error. Its weird that it works for the function component and not for the class component. I think it has to do something with passing the props.

Comment: my case is weird. I used it as a functional class and i get that warning.

Answer (score 2):

In your class component, the `key` attribute needs to be on the wrapper `div` element.

Comment: Because the `div` is the parent element in the `map` function. You can read that the `key` must be on the parent element, in the official doc here : https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

Comment: I added the key in the div and still getting the same error. Its weird that it works for the function component and not for the class component. I think it has to do something with passing the props.

Comment: @LeTuanAnh Please post your changed code so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

In React, in a iteration, each iteration **root element** should have a key attribute.

In your example, you gave key attribute to VideoItem component. That's the wrapping div who should have it.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import VideoItem from './VideoItem';

class VideoList extends Component {
    render() { 
        const renderedItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
            return <div key={video.id.videoId}><VideoItem video={video} selectedVideo={this.props.selectedVideo}/></div>
        })
        return(
            <div>{renderedItems}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default VideoList;
```

Comment: this change didn't work either. still getting the same warning

Comment: I added the key in the div and still getting the same error. Its weird that it works for the function component and not for the class component. I think it has to do something with passing the props.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your id is not always unique?

Try this (adding idx in map fn)

```
const renderedItems = this.props.videos.map((video, idx) => {
     return <div><VideoItem key={idx} video={video} 
     selectedVideo={this.props.selectedVideo}/></div>
})
```

Comment: Using index as key is a very bad idea. If I consume this component twice, you will have repeated keys

Comment: Don't use index as keys. Sometimes you also want some other `compnent` with `<VideoItem>`  in the container. The it will give error

Comment: And this would not solve the problem at all, the `key` needs to either be in the `div` or the `div` needs to be removed

Comment: Why? I found this pattern in Stefan Stoyanow book :)

Comment: @KamilNaja I call this component twice with similar length list. Now I will have 2 elements with same keys. How do you expect react to fetch correct element using this key?